# A vector $\{0,1\}$ combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways are there to choose $n$ distinct vectors in $\{0,1\}^{n}$ each of Hamming weight $w$ such that there is $k$ of them that will agree at exactly $s$ positions? Is there a nice description of this space of $n$ vectors?

Comment: Do you just want there to exist *at least one* set of $k$ vectors that have $s$ of their components in common? Or do you want a set of vectors that, for any $k$ of them, agree pairwise at $s$ positions?

Comment: Ok forgot crucial component.